# Chrome debugger breaks at wrong point or not at all (typescript)

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

At first I thought my breakpoints simply weren't working and went on a wild goose chase. Then I used "debugger" in my code and things got weird... From what I understand the keyword "debugger" is basically akin to placing a breakpoint via code.

Here's an example:

[image]
You can see I placed "debugger" where I'd been placing a breakpoint but instead the code highlighted is in a different function. However, looking at the Scope it seems the correct code is executing:

[image]

I've noticed too that if I place random breakpoints on in the Chrome Dev Tools .ts file, they will sometimes be hit when code elsewhere in the file is being executed.

This makes debugging basically pointless.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Have you worked it out?

If there's any other info I'm not providing that would help please let me know.

**Edit:**

@Matt Zeunert suggested the source map might be off and gave me a link (in comments) so here's a link to the results. While the results are nearly incomprehensible to me, I'd say it looks off.
[SOURCE MAP RESULTS](http://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/#base64,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,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,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)

Comment: Maybe the source maps aren't generated correctly by TypeScript. You could try uploading your source map here and seeing where changeForm maps to. http://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/#custom

Comment: Hey I'm not sure how all that works but I'd say it seems to be mapped wrong, or at least in some incomprehensible way... I can't paste the long link in here so I'll put it in the question.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted my .js and .js.map files and rebuilt my project and that does seem to have done the trick! Any idea how it would get all off like that?

Comment: @Methodician Maybe the map didn't get built last time and it was using the version from the previous build? If it was built from VS, I wouldn't be at all surprised.

Comment: Yeah I'm not terribly shocked either. It was VS. WTF do I do? Microsoft invented (in a sense) TypeScript but their own IDE doesn't properly support it. I've had nothing but frustration trying to use VS with TypeScript. I always get things working when I create a new project and inevitably things stop working for no apparent reason down the road. Now, my map files aren't right. Last time it was worse and my transpiled JS was wrong so things crashed constantly. Any clues?